# Fused Location Api Location

Tags: android

I have used Fused Location api to get latitude and longitude but the problem is itsit's saying that the google api client isntisn't connected yet i dont. I don't know where iI am wrong plz help me out.

My Splash Activity where iI am using Fused Api ::

Note :: GPS Tracker is a class here i used which uses location manager i haven't used it in the program i. I just used it to check whether the Gps is on or off.

I too added all the permissions in manifest file.

```
package com.example.na462.sunshine;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.*;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import java.net.URL;

import static android.R.attr.animation;
import static com.example.na462.sunshine.R.id.MainList;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity implements Animation.AnimationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
Animation animation, TextAnimation;
ImageView imageView;
ImageView ErrorImage;
LocationRequest locationRequest;
TextView AnimationText;
Button ErrorReload;
private FusedLocationProviderApi fusedLocationProviderApi = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
LinearLayout Layout;
Receiver receiver;
boolean Connection;
GPSTracker gpsTracker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(60 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(15 * 1000);


    AnimationText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextAnimation);
    ErrorReload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ErrorReload);
    imageView = (ImageView) (SplashActivity.this).findViewById(R.id.Animation);
    Layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Error);
    ErrorImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Nointernet);
    gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(SplashActivity.this);
    gpsTracker.getLocation();
    receiver = new Receiver();
    Connection = receiver.internetconnection(SplashActivity.this);

    if (!Connection || !GPSEnabled.GPS) {
        imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ErrorImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        AnimationText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    } else {
        AnimationText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Layout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ErrorImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                googleApiClient.disconnect();
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, ScrollingActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                finish();
            }
        }, 8000);


        animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
        animation.setAnimationListener(this);
        imageView.startAnimation(animation);


        TextAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.blink);
        TextAnimation.setAnimationListener(this);
        AnimationText.startAnimation(TextAnimation);

        googleApiClient.connect();



    }
}


@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

}

// Its an onclick Method For Retry if there isnt any conncection or GPS Estabished



@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        onLocationUpdates();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient,this);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    onLocationUpdates();
}

private void onLocationUpdates() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    ValuesToPass.Latitude = location.getLatitude();
    ValuesToPass.Longitude = location.getLongitude();
    CordinatesLoc.Latitude = Math.round(location.getLatitude());
    CordinatesLoc.Longitude = Math.round(location.getLongitude());
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Google recently released a new API which makes this process a whole lot easier and you don't need a GoogleApiClient anymore. I strongly advise you to use this API instead.

See the example below for how to use it.

```
FusedLocationProviderClient client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);
client.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, pendingIntent)
        .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            Log.d("requestLocationUpdates", "result: " + task.getResult());
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            String errorMessage;
            if (e instanceof ApiException) {
                errorMessage = ((ApiException) e).getStatusMessage();
            } else {
                errorMessage = e.getMessage();
            }
            Log.d("requestLocationUpdate", "failed: " + errorMessage);
        });
```

In your case you might replace `context` with `this` to refer to your activity instead of a context reference.

`pendingIntent` is the PendingIntent instance that defines what to do with received location updates.

Comment: my app target from API level 9, please help me for location, fused API hang when i request for location. not receive any callback.like failed or suspend or anything.

Comment: don't target api 9. Nobody on the planet uses api 9 anymore

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, unfortunately i have to use this, so you have any solution for my issue? please help if you have. >> "fused API hang when i request for location. not receive any callback.like failed or suspend or anything". Location service is on in high accuracy, request interval 10 second.

Comment: @TimCastelijns how to call requestLocationUpdates every x time and also on every x meter  please help me